# Is every optimization problem defined on function space referred to as "calculus of variation"?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Suppose that we want to choose a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x)$ from a class of functions $\mathcal{F} = \{ g| g(x) = wx, w \in \mathbb{R}$} such that it minimizes the functional
\begin{equation}
J(f) = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n |f(x_i) - y_i|
\end{equation}
$x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}$

Is this an example of "calculus of variation"?

I was told in the past that any optimization involving minimising over a function space is "calculus of variation". But I was looking at some examples, and it seems that there are a [lot more integrals involved in the usual calculus of variation problems](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cv.pdf) as compared to this problem.

Can someone confirm or deny?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course your ${\cal F}$ is a function space, but these functions are terribly restricted. In fact we have a single free real variable $w$ which has to be chosen such that the quantity
$$q(w):={1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n \bigl|w\, x_i-y_i\bigr|$$
for given  sample points $(x_i,y_i)$ $\,(1\leq i\leq n)$ is minimized. This is a standard problem, and has a single solution $w_*\in{\mathbb R}$. No "free" candidating functions are involved here.

For a *real variational problem* the feasible set of candidating functions $g$ would be an infinite dimensional set of "arbitrary"  functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$, satisfying some conditions like $g(a)=g(b)=0$, or similar. Only then we would obtain, e.g., a differential equation that potential optimal functions $g$ would have to satisfy.